# Multiplying numbers with its line in text file

Tags: c++

How do you read text file with single numbers in each line, then multiply each number with the number of its line then output the results. 
was able to display but fail to times each number with its number of line.

using c++

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: By doing it. If you are having difficulty, you will need to show the attempt that fails and explain in detail what you have done to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop to count how many lines have been read in.

```
std::ifstream input( "filename.ext" );

// get each line in file
std::string line = "";
for( int line_num = 0; getline( input, line ); line_num++) {
    // convert line to int
    int num = std::stoi(line)

    // multiply num by the line number
    int product = line * line_num;

}
```